# Storing a .pfx certificate file securely in a .net core 2 application?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, pfx

I have a public private key certificate (.pfx) that I need to use in my .net core 2 application.

My application is hosted using Azure (free tier currently).

I'm not sure where the best place to keep the certificate is. I know that the folder where servable assets go is 'wwwroot', but of course I don't want to serve the certificate, I just want it to be accessible by my code to authenticate against a third party API.

Is there a place/method this can be achieved?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Have you considered using Azure Key Vault? It is meant to store your secrets and certificates, so a great solution. It does cost some money of course.

Comment: In one sense, it doesn't matter. It just needs to be in some place where you're application can access it (with permission) and which is not publicly served (i.e. *not* wwwroot).

Comment: @ChrisPratt that sounds like what I want to do initially. So I should just be able to store it in a folder in the project root and target it that way? It seems to work locally but not when I publish (saying cannot find file). I'm about confused about what actually physically gets published.

Answer (score 1):

For an Azure web app you can add a certificate (.pfx) on the service plan "hosting" the web app. Once uploaded, the certificate will be accessible from your code. 
Then, you just need the add the following appSetting "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" with the certificate thumbprint as value to allow the web app to use the certificate.

The process can be done in two steps :

1. On the portal Azure, you can upload your certificate from the "SSL certificates" menu on your web app dashboard
2. Add the AppSetting WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES = yourThumbprint

Another solution would be to place you certificate in Azure KeyVault.